# Определить наличие макроса в файлах типа .dot или .xlsm

Tags: excel, vbscript

Как определить наличие макроса в файлах типа .dot или .xlsm
т.е. в случае обнаружения хоть одного макроса в файле вывести True или в обратном случае False.
В какую сторону копать и при помощи какого ЯП можно решить эту задачу?

Comment: Эм.. Вывести чем?

Comment: да чем угодно, Java, Python, C#, VBS.  или на экран в консоли или в текстовый файл

Comment: В docx и xlsx макросов вообще не бывает. Они бывают в doc и xls, а так же в docm и xlsm.

Comment: Но в самом файле макросов же нет?

Comment: Прошу прощения, формат xlsm